# How to call asynchronous functions in cascade?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Given the following code, I would like to know if there is a way to reduce it to a single line without using parentheses to resolve the promise.

```
context = await browser.new_context(
    viewport={
        "width": 1600,
        "height": 1200,
    },
    device_scale_factor=2,
)

page = await context.new_page()
```

Something like this:

```
page = await pipe(browser.new_context(viewport={"width": 1600, "height": 1200}, device_scale_factor=2), lambda c: c.new_page())
```

Or this:

```
result = await some_async_function().then(another_async_function).then(yet_another_async_function)
```

Comment: _"reduce it to a single line"_ - why? What is wrong with the way it is? Is it too readable?

Comment: It was just an example.

Comment: Your can do `await (await browser.new_context(...)).new_page()`, but that is really ugly.

Comment: > without using parentheses to resolve the promise.

Comment: Example of what? A nicely readable code that you want to turn into an unreadable oneliner?

Comment: @freakish have you read my question? I was looking for a functional solution, like using pipe.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for sure you can do that

```
page = await (await browser.new_context(viewport={"width": 1600, "height": 1200}, device_scale_factor=2)).new_page()
```

Comment: > without using parentheses to resolve the promise.

Comment: if your code is in python, this should work